# I've created a singleton class, how can I call it from my ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, viewcontroller

I've created the following singleton class, but I'm not sure how to call it from my ViewControllers (sorry for the newb question)? I've imported it into my ViewController (#import cloudStore.h), but what line of code should I be using in a ViewController's viewDidLoad in order to "use" it?

**cloudStore.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface cloudStore : NSObject

+(cloudStore *)singleton;

@end
```

**cloudStore.m**

```
#import "cloudStore.h"

@implementation cloudStore

+(cloudStore *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static cloudStore *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[cloudStore alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

@end
```

Comment: You should change the capitalization on `cloudStore` to `CloudStore` for readability and then the code becomes `[CloudStore singleton]` to get a reference to the shared instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do

```
cloudStore *aCloudStore = [cloudStore singleton];
```

in order to get a reference to your single instance of cloudStore.

Comment: Ok so strangely enough when I do this, XCode says, "No visible interface for cloudStore declares the selector singleton"

Comment: Also, just for convention sake you should start your class names with a capital letter and continue using camel case notation. Example: CloudStore, BigGearBox, SmallWiedget.

Comment: My guess is that it got confused because of the class name 'cloudStore' and the variable name 'cloudStore'. I've updated my response. Also why class names should start with an upper case (to avoid collisions with variables)

Comment: So hold on: the name of my singleton and the name of the defined value (eg.  NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *CloudStore) in my ViewController shouldn't be the same? Doesn't it need to be?

Comment: @Brittany: No, you can name whatever name for your singleton. Like StorageManager or anything that is meaningful. Also instead of naming your method `singleton` name it like `sharedStorageManager` or something else.

Comment: No your variable name can be anything you want. You should just make sure that its type is the class name and that you really do instantiate a new class of that type. In the case of a singleton it returns an already instantiated object.

So in your case you are looking at:

CloudStore *myCloudStore = [CloudStore singleton]; 

(After renaming cloudStore to the uppercase CloudStore.